# How to generate unique id's within jsrender template

Tags: jsrender

I'm new to JSrender and had trouble generating unique id's within JSrender template, as it pretty much outputs anything written within the text/x-jsrender block (except predefined tags)
Here's my code:

HTML: `<div id="showjsrender"></div>`

Template Script:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender id="tmpl">
<div class="displayTodo" id="displayTodo"+uniqueID+"">
..
</div>
</script>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function call(variable, index){
    var template = $.templates("#tmpl");
    var htmlOutput = template.render(variable, index);
    $("#showJSrender").html(htmlOutput);
}
</script>
```

JS file(external file):

```
app.editTask = function(e){
        todoArr[e].editOn = true;
        document.getElementById("displayTodo"+e+"").innerHTML = "";
        editCalled(todoArr, e);
}
```

I tried to send the entire todoArr array and re-render the entire array and generate unique id by using the array's index (getIndex()), but while sending single indexed data every time, I've found it difficult to generate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper (http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers):

```
<div ... id="displayTodo{{:~uniqueID()}}" >div1...</div>
<div ... id="displayTodo{{:~uniqueID()}}" >div2...</div>
...
```

with a global helper:

```
var counter = 0;
$.views.helpers("uniqueID", function() { return counter++; });
...
var htmlOutput = template.render(model);
...
```

or a helper passed in to the render call:

```
var counter = 0;
...
var htmlOutput = template.render(model, {uniqueID:
    function() { return counter++; }
});
...
```